# Repeating element's content/text in aria-label property

Tags: css, web, accessibility, wai-aria

In the example below I have a `aria-label` inside my `span`, which has as content/text the exact same value as the `aria-label`: which, in this case, is whatever the variable `$order->status` gets to be.

```
<span aria-label="{{ $order->status }}" class="ui-badge">{{ $order->status }}</span>
```

As far as I know, one shoudln't use any `aria` property if the content makes the job; but in this case, using the propert would make my CSS much easier and descriptive, since I can style for each status without having to create new classes or using BEM's `--flag`. In this case, is the `aria-label` allowed or not?

```
&[aria-label="Pago"] {
  background-color: $green;
}
```

Comment: Many screen readers only read aria-label  only when the element is interactive / focusable. For a simple span, it won't work everywhere. I recommend using visually hidden text if you don't want it to be displayed on screen instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aria-label` works best on interactive elements (such as links, buttons, and form elements) and [landmarks](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#landmark_roles) (such as `<nav>` and `<main>`).  It does not work (or has very spotty support) when used on elements that don't have a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) (such as a `<div>` or `<span>`).

See "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)", in particular the third last bullet point:

> Don't use aria-label or aria-labelledby on a span or div unless it's given a role.

If the only reason you're using it is to make your CSS code easier, I would recommend using a [`data-` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) and checking that attribute in your CSS.

```
<span data-myattribute="{{ $order->status }}" class="ui-badge">{{ $order->status }}</span>
```

```
[data-myattribute="Pago"] {
  background-color: $green;
}
```

See also:

- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) (developer.mozilla.org)
- [A Complete Guide to Data Attributes](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/) (css-tricks.com)